# Lusin's area integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was reading "Steven G. Krantz - Handbook of Complex Variables" and came around a complex surface integral called "Lusin's area integral":

If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a domain and $\varphi: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is a one-to-one analytic function, then $\varphi(\Omega)$ is a domain, and

$\text{area}(\varphi(\Omega)) = \int\limits_{\Omega} | \varphi'(x + \mathrm{i} y) |^2 \ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$

The book doesn't include a proof so I tried to come up with one myself:

Since every one-to-one analytic function can be written as:

$\varphi(z) = e^{i\theta} \frac{a - z}{1 - \overline{a}z}$ for a suitable $\theta$ and $|a| < 1$ it suffices to show the claim for $\tilde \varphi(z) = \frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a} z}$ with $|a| < 1$.

But now I'm stuck and I can't find any info on this integral on the internet. Calculating $|\tilde \varphi'(z)|^2$ gives me something I can't integrate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it. It's actually really easy. All you have to know is that $\varphi(\Omega) = \Omega$ and that $|\varphi'(z)|^2$ is the determinant of the jacobian. Then the claim follows by simple substitution.